# method getfragmentmanager() is undefined

Tags: android, fragment

I am making a view pager to make a slide show for images. I took code from Android developers, but I was facing some issues, fragment was not recognized, I think it was because my android was 2.33. So to solve that I imported a jar file android.support.v4.jar
My issues were resolved but now I am getting this error that getfragmentmanager() is undefined
and another issue "The method invalidateOptionsMenu() is undefined for the type new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){}"

Here is my code, can any one please help ?? 
My platform is 2.3.3 and api level is 10 and in manifest I have this

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Code :

```
package com.example.profilemanagment;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.*;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;



public class ScreenSlideActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    /**
     * The number of pages (wizard steps) to show in this demo.
     */
    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 5;

    /**
     * The pager widget, which handles animation and allows swiping horizontally to access previous
     * and next wizard steps.
     */
    private ViewPager mPager;

    /**
     * The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget.
     */
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_slide);

        // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // When changing pages, reset the action bar actions since they are dependent
                // on which page is currently active. An alternative approach is to have each
                // fragment expose actions itself (rather than the activity exposing actions),
                // but for simplicity, the activity provides the actions in this sample.
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        });
    }




    /**
     * A simple pager adapter that represents 5 {@link ScreenSlidePageFragment} objects, in
     * sequence.
     */
    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return ScreenSlidePageFragment.create(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from the docs.

When using this class (`FragmentActivity`) as opposed to new platform's built-in fragment and loader support, you must use the `getSupportFragmentManager()` and `getSupportLoaderManager()` methods respectively to access those features.

Since you are extending `FragmentActivity` use `getSupportFragmentManager()`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html

Check the docs

`FragmentActivity` does not have `getFragmentManager()`

Comment: what about invalidateOptionsMenu() ?? should add support here too?

Comment: public void invalidateOptionsMenu ()

Added in API level 11
Declare that the options menu has changed, so should be recreated. The onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) method will be called the next time it needs to be displayed. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu()

Comment: @user2061477 use `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()`

Comment: @user2061477 `invalidateOptionsMenu()` added in api 11. your min sdk is 8.

Comment: @Raghunandan I have a `ViewPagerAdapter` extends `PagerAdapter` when i am using `autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);` the `getFragmentManager` inside instantiate item method showing can not resolve. can you suggest me how to fix this.

Comment: @jaydroider you can post a new question with relevant piece of codes and someone will help you.